# Split string on individual cells - VBA function

Tags: excel, string, vba, list

I need help spliting a string separated by ";" and make a list as shown in this example:

```
         |        A          |
|----------------------------|
|  Row1  | Name1;Name2;Name3 |
|  Row2  |      Name1        |
|  Row3  |      Name2        |
|  Row4  |      Name3        |
```

How can I achieve this with a VBA function?

Thanks in advance,

MD

Comment: `Split("Name1;Name2;Name3", ";")` returns a 3-element array. The values in that array can be put in a worksheet. What have you tried?

Comment: Why *VBA*, you can do this with worksheet functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like writing non-work-related code over lunch:

```
Sub NamesToList()
    'Assumes that a cell is selected which contains a string which
    'looks something like "Name1;Name2;Name3"
    'The sub splits that list and then puts the values immediately
    'below the selected cell. Warning: this doesn't check if there is
    'room for those values and will overwrite existing values with no
    'warning

    Dim A As Variant, n As Long, R As Range
    Set R = Selection
    A = Split(R.Value, ";")
    n = UBound(A)
    Range(R.Offset(1), R.Offset(n + 1)).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(A)
End Sub
```

If you invoke this sub while `A1` is selected, the names will be automatically inserted in `A2:A4`. No error-checking is done, so you should probably tweak this code to make sure that it doesn't e.g. overwrite any values.

Comment: Thanks John! Just what I was looking for.